# How to debug Android applications when your emulators are slow?

Tags: android-emulator

**How to debug Android applications when your emulators are slow?**

This is one of the most common problems you face when you don’t have a high end machine to run the Android Emulator. As you know, the Android emulator is damn slow and especially if you want to work with the Google API version 18 or above then it really sucks. To render maps on emulator is a pain.

Comment: This question will elicit responses based on opinion rather than fact. Consider a more direct question. That being said, nothing beats emulation on an actual piece of hardware IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple and easy solution here.

http://www.j2eebrain.com/java-J2ee-how-to-debug-android-applications-when-your-emulators-are-slow.html